# Apple Watch App : Get Login state of user on iOS app for 'Not Running' state

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I'm looking for a way to access the user's login state on an iOS app when it is in the ***Not Running(not launched)***.

For the iPhone-app, on sign-in and sign-out, a Userdefault value is updated

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isLogin, forKey: UserDefaults.UserDefaultsKeys.isLogin.rawValue)
```

Currently, there is a session in place to send a message to watch when both (iPhone and Watch) are in an active state based on the user's login state (true/false)

```
session.sendMessage(["isLogin" : false], replyHandler: nil)
```

The target is to ensure that if a user is signed out of iPhone-app when the watch is not in range, and once the watch is in close proximity, the watch should get the user login state even if the iPhone app is in a "***Not Running***" state.

Answer (score 0):

Consider WCSession/updateApplicationContext

> The system sends context data when the opportunity arises, with the
> goal of having the data ready to use by the time the counterpart wakes
> up.